# How to create smart collections in Lightroom for hierarchical keywords?

Tags: lightroom, keywords, smart-collections

I want to make smart collection according to my hierarchical keywords set on my images.
Take a look at included image to have a view about my scenario.[image]

What criteria should I define for my smart collection in order to contain only images that are '_shutterstock < _accepted' ? If I added this as filter term it will return also images that are marked as '_dreamstime <_accepted' :-? 
I want to filter my images in such a way that I may know which images are submitted to site A, B, C and if they were accepted or rejected.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Lightroom doesn't do well with understanding hierarchical keywords for its filters, however you could try setting the collection to match ALL the conditions and have one for _shutterstock and one for _accepted.  Any image with the shutterstock accepted keyword will have both shutterstock and accepted since they are nested.

Comment: Presumably an image might be in "_dreamstime < _accepted" and "_shutterstock < _rejected".  Matching on ("_shutterstock" AND "_accepted") would improperly match such an image.

Comment: @coneslayer - you would then need an accepted that is specific to dreamstock, such as _dsaccepted.  Not really ideal, but I can't think of a better option.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a combination of **Keywords** and **Colors** (or **Keywords** and **Ratings**) might work if Lightroom's keyword support falls short.

For example, you could set up your smart collection to match all the conditions, with the conditions including a **Keyword** of *_shutterstock* and a **Color** of *green* for accepted.

YMMV depending on whether you already have other uses for colors or ratings in your workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Lightroom just can't handle hierarchical keywords well, and their filtering is weak here (for no good reason). I tried this a few years back, and it drove me nuts making it reliable, so I stopped trying. Instead, I create keywords that are specific and unique, and which don't contain spaces for terms like this:

Shutterstock
    shutterstock_accepted
    shutterstock_rejected
    shutterstock_etc

Doing it that way gives you a keyword you can use reliably AND which won't trigger false positives when you do something that uses the same keywords in different contexts

Comment: yes - after a while I found out that too. In the while I also developed a strategy which I hope to share soon ;)

Comment: if it helps, what I do is here:http://www.chuqui.com/thoughts-on-lightroom-keywords/